# admin-on-rest ReferenceInput works for Edit but not Create

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

For some reason, the ReferenceInput works fine on my Edit form; but on Create form, it shows as disabled and empty (I use the same code for both form). It also doesn't show any error in chrome dev tools. Do I have to do any additional stuff for the Create form to work? Thanks

Comment: please share your code

Comment: you may have to set allowEmpty on referenceInput in create

Comment: @kunalpareek ahhh that's true, either that or set default value, I guess. Should have been mentioned in the document. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Note "allowEmpty" in ReferenceInput

```
<Create title="My title" {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
        <TextInput label= "field 1" source="f1"  validate={[ required, minLength(3), maxLength(20) ]} />
        <ReferenceInput label="field 2" source="f2" validate={[ required ]} reference="reference1" allowEmpty>
            <AutocompleteInput optionText="f3" />
        </ReferenceInput>
    </SimpleForm>
</Create>
```